# Ajax passing formatted text to other php file and diplay as in text area

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, textarea

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#buttonclick').click(function(){
            fulltext=$('#fulltext').val();
            $('#display').load('action.php?fulltext='+fulltext);
            });
          });
  </script>
<input type='button' id='buttonclick' value='Load'>

<textarea rows="30" cols="70" id='fulltext' name='fulltext' style="resize: none;">

</textarea>

<div id='display'></div>
```

The action.php file is as follows

```
<?php
$abcd= $_GET['fulltext'];
echo '<pre>'.$abcd.'</pre>';
?>
```

All what I want is to display the contents of text area in div(id='display') in the same format as it is written in (id=fulltext). For example:

```
      he is who.
      who is he.
```

In my case the above content of text area is being appended together and being displayed as

```
he is who. who is he
```

that is the format is changed. Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really get rid of the extra }); as Rohan Kumar suggested.
But the problem is that you are not encoding properly your parameters.

Use

```
$('#display').load('action.php?fulltext='+encodeURIComponent(fulltext));
```

and it should work

Comment: Exactly..That's It..:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) in **php page** like,

```
<?php
    $abcd= $_GET['fulltext'];
    echo htmlentities($abcd);
?>
```

**Updated** you are applying extra **});** in your **js code** remove the last **});**

or add **$(function(){** in your code

```
$(function(){// add this line in your code
    $('#buttonclick').click(function(){
        fulltext=$('#fulltext').val();
        $('#display').load('action.php?fulltext='+fulltext);
    });
});// this was extra
```